# URL image not able set new content in ImageView, always it is taking old image from cache

Tags: android, image, imageview

when i am setting the image to Imageview from URL, it is showing me old image in mobile. but showing correct(new) image in emulator.

```
public class URLImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage=null;
Context context;
public URLImage(ImageView bmImage ,Context context) {
    this.bmImage = bmImage;
    bmImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
    this.context=context;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();

        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),result);
    bmImage.setImageDrawable(d);
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but why not use bmImage.setImageBitmap(result) instead of those two lines in onPostExecute? Also, do you know what the first argument of new BitmapDrawable() is doing? The developer guide says "
Create drawable from a bitmap, setting initial target density based on the display metrics of the resources.", but im not sure what "initial target density" is.

Comment: i have used bmImage.setImageBitmap(result). but it does not work so i have changed to bmImage.setImageDrawable(d); . but it is also not working